# How to add a button to toolbar, and top of menu

Tags: android, firefox-addon

Is it possible to add a button to the toolbar of android firefox, and also the top of the pop up menu as shown in this screenshot below:

[image]

edit:
just found a screenshot of an addon that had some other addons installed that added a button up there, pleease see addon screenshots:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/quitnow/

here is the screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/143/143566.png?modified=1411168623))</sub>

see that nightly globe and whatever that is to the left of it, im trying to do same :) top row in this second picture is toolbar button icons that would show in the top toolbar when there is enough screen space im interested in learning how to add to 1st and second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [Developing for Firefox Mobile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development) marks all UI APIs as *Not supported*. Mozilla uses the native UI of Android to build Firefox for Android. Therefore everything related to XUL might not work at all.

Now there is an [Extensions for Firefox for Android API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API) and the only thing related to what you'd like to achieve can be found with [PageActions.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API/PageActions.jsm), which can be used like:

```
Pageactions.add({
  icon: "drawable://alert_app",
  title: "My page action",
  clickCallback: function() { win.alert("Clicked!"); }
});
```

These are added to the toolbar, but displayed inside of the adressbar not beside it. In the screenshot you posted, the little book icon is a pageaction. But there's a limitation as well:

> ***NOTE:*** A maximum of two page action items will be shown to users at a time. If users have three page actions showing, an overflow menu will appear to handle the extra ones. Your action has NO control over whether its shown in the urlbar or overflow. Don't depend on your page action always showing in the main urlbar.

The buttons you find at the top of the menu can't be changed neither. The star at the left is for the bookmarks and the graph on the right is the button for sharing the web page. The space inbetween is used to display the last two applications you shared the web page with.

So basically, what you'd like to do is not possible at all and the addons I know trying to achieve something similar use page actions.